# python 2.7 need to grep a particular word from a file

Tags: python-2.7

I need to grep an expression from a file below:Please help i want to grep the word after disk@ till comma.

```
cat out1 boot-device=/pci@400/pci@2/pci@0/pci@e/scsi@/disk@w5000cca025884d5d,0:a rootmirror rootdisk boot-device-index=0
```

Comment: Grep is a shell tool. In what way is this a Python question?

Comment: I mean want to get word disk@till comma.Please check Below:                disk@w5000cca025884d5d

Comment: I assume by "grep" you mean "use regular expressions"? Python has a library for that. See below:

Comment: Take a look at this tool: https://regex101.com/ (be sure to set it to Python at the left) and the Python Regular Expression https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? It'll print out "disk@w5000cca025884d5d"

```
import re
file_object = open("input", "r")
for line in file_object:    
    m = re.search('.*disk@(.*),.*', line)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i am able to print the work but i do not want comma.Please check:                                                                                                           disk@w5000cca025884d5d,

Comment: sure, just move it outside the () as I've done above.

Comment: Thank a lot it worked.But my fault my requirement is acutally to search expression after disk@and one character less before comma.                 I am really sorry for this.

Comment: You can just move the disk@ expression outside the brackets as I did with the comma. But I don't understand what you mean by one less? So you want w5000cca025884d5 and not w5000cca025884d5d? If you just want to drop the last character you can add a [:-1] like this: print(m.group(1)[:-1])

Comment: Thanks a lot for prompt response appreciated.It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Might need to escape the comma as a special character:

```
import re

s = 'cat out1 boot-device=/pci@400/pci@2/pci@0/pci@e/scsi@0/disk@w5000cca025884d5d,0:a rootmirror rootdisk boot-device-index=0'
match = re.search(r'disk@(.*)\,', s)

if match:
    print match.group(1)
```

outputs:

```
w5000cca025884d5d
```

Comment: From the output i want to remove first and last alphabets.This is my requirement.Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Ok, but didn't the other answer solve your question?

Comment: maybe you want to do as described in the other answer's comments, slice off the first and last characters: `print match.group(1)[1:-1]` -> `5000cca025884d5`?